# How can I do the Senku game on Maude?

Tags: maude-system

I would like to understand how the Senku game can be programmed in Maude. If possible, I am seeking two distinct solutions: one that employs objects, and another that utilizes a list of lists. Additionally, I would like to establish a data type called "Board" to represent the Senku game board. This data type should, at a minimum, incorporate an operation named "count," denoted as op count : Board -> Nat, which calculates the number of tokens present on the board. Furthermore, I am interested in defining the rules necessary to model the various movements that can be executed on the Senku game board.

I extend my gratitude to anyone willing to assist with this endeavor.

I have tried to do it, but it is too complex for me to understand. There are not many examples to refer to, and the documentation is not sufficient for me to complete this exercise.